# can i enable multiple buttons using a loop?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
        btnA.Enabled = true;
        btnB.Enabled = true;
        btnC.Enabled = true;
        btnD.Enabled = true;
        btnE.Enabled = true;
        btnF.Enabled = true;
        btnG.Enabled = true;
        btnH.Enabled = true;
        btnI.Enabled = true;
        btnJ.Enabled = true;
        btnK.Enabled = true;
        btnL.Enabled = true;
        btnM.Enabled = true;
        btnN.Enabled = true;
        btnO.Enabled = true;
        btnP.Enabled = true;
        btnQ.Enabled = true;
        btnR.Enabled = true;
        btnS.Enabled = true;
        btnT.Enabled = true;
        btnU.Enabled = true;
        btnV.Enabled = true;
        btnW.Enabled = true;
        btnX.Enabled = true;
        btnY.Enabled = true;
        btnZ.Enabled = true;
```

i am doing a hangman game, and i have to enable all these buttons when the user clicks start/restart. Is there anyway that i can remove this redundant code by looping this?

it is a W F A

Comment: Just start with them enabled and then disable them in the OnClick as they're used.

Comment: Is this a web application?

Comment: You should specify if this is a Winforms, WPF, Windows8 XAML, WebForms, ... project using a tag as for each technology the answer is different.

Comment: `WFA` could either mean WinForms Application or WebForms Application...  Which is it?

Answer (score 2):

Create a list/array/collection of buttons and do it in a for loop.

Comment: Or better yet, create a list of model objects, create a button for each model object, binded to the model object and then change the state of the model objects. If he really needs to keep it "backwards", he could go over the children of the form/window and enable all the children of type button with a name of the form "btn" + letter.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(var b in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{ 
   b.Enabled = true;
}
```

Add some LINQ. Add a where clause to exclude buttons you don't want to target.

Comment: he said he has to enable multiple buttons, not ALL buttons of the container.

Comment: It can be done one a container instead of the whole form. Same idea

Comment: Need more info in order to white list buttons, but it looks like it's fairly sequential with a naming convention

Answer (score 0):

Do something like

```
foreach(Control ctrl in this.Controls)
{
    if(ctrl is IButtonControl)
    {
        ctrl.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop with type checking ;)

```
foreach(Button btn in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    // Invert the current state.
    btn.Enabled = !btn.Enabled;
}
```

That's all ;)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it could be because someone already posted an answer that is almost exactly the same as this.

Comment: I was writing my answer and when I had submited it, 3 other answer appears :c

Comment: Yeah, happens to me all the time.  These people are quick!

Comment: ^^, stop flood or we will got downvotted again xD

Answer (score -1):

You don't specify, but **if this is for a web application** I would recommend using javascript/html to do this.  For example, if you use jQuery in your application the code below should do it:

```
$("button").prop("disabled",true);
```

This will avoid a needless postback to the server and seems simpler than any solution you will be able to implement in the code behind.